# Laravel: PHP or Javascript in displaying data?

Tags: laravel

What is the recommended way in displaying data in Laravel?

Using Javascript? (Jquery and ajax request)

or

Using PHP? (data will be displayed in blade, example: `<p> {{$data_here}} </p>`)

Currently I'm using Jquery and Ajax in displaying the data retrieved from server. I was wondering if using PHP in displaying the data will be faster than the Javascript, since PHP handles things at the server side and JavaScript handles things on the browser side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server Side**

- Search engines are able to crawl the website leading to better SEO
  impact
- Site interactions are non-rich
- Faster initial page load times
- The complete page reloads at each request
- Frequent and multiple requests to the server
- The overall rendering of the page is slow

**client-side**

- Websites are rendered faster after the initial load
- Negative impact to SEO if not implemented correctly
- Optimal for web applications
- The initial load time may increase
- Thorough selection of JavaScript libraries
- An external library is required in most cases Site interactions are
  rich

> > > > Read more >>>
> > > >         https://storylens.com/@manjunath/server-side-vs-client-side-rendering---an-in-depth-overview

Comment: thank you for narrowing it down. This Is what I need